# Azure Sql db with Tera bytes

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a very structured data that that i want to insert to sql DB.

The table looks like this (int, int, int, int)

the current data size will be around 1TB and will increase in time to be a few TB

I have looked at the azure sql data warehouse but it's not suitable for me.

is there another solution that scales the SQL db size according to the data ?

I want to use az

Comment: not really a question for stack overflow

Comment: As @DavidLee said - not really a good fit for StackOverflow, as there's really no "right" or "best" way to save your data. Also - there are no *tables* - just *collections*, which don't conform to the strict-schema rules of relational tables. As for overhead, that's easy enough to test on your own by writing a bunch of content and then looking at consumption metrics (and don't forget - it's not just data - it's indexes as well). As for the question itself: Unfortunately off-topic, as it's very broad / opinion-soliciting.